# Random ID fetching from Database

Tags: php, mysql, database, image, random

Want to fetch random ID from the database which is a primary key.
So I can retrieve the corresponding path of the image.

How can i do that?

And also Eg. Out of 100%.. There should be 40% chances of fetching data.. while 60% of showing msg like "Data not fetch.. please reload again"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to return a single random row you can use;

```
SELECT columnlist FROM tablename order by RAND() LIMIT 1
```

This method is pretty slow however as [this link](http://akinas.com/pages/en/blog/mysql_random_row/) explains, with alternative methods.

Comment: What does LIMIT do in query?

Comment: You do want only 1 row, don't you?

Comment: As you'd expect, 'LIMIT's to '1' result. If you wanted to return more just change that number.

Comment: No I want maximum time the user should not fetch data...
I mean the possibility of fetching data on every reload should be lowered!

Comment: That isn't even loosely mentioned in your question...?

Comment: Eg. Out of 100%.. There should be 40% chances of fetching data.. while 60% of showing msg like "Data not fetch.. please reload again"

Comment: I would edit it..if you want